# Foreach - Condições dentro de um period

Tags: php, sql, data, foreach

É possível colocar uma condição if/else dentro de um foreach? Abaixo parte de um código, onde insere no banco o intervalo de datas via $_POST. A questão é: É possível colocar um if/else dentro desse intervalo? Ex: Se for sábado, não preeche, ou se for sabado preencha determinada hora.

```
    $start = new DateTime($_POST["data1"]); 


    $end = new DateTime($_POST["data2"]); 


   $interval = new DateInterval("P1D"); 



    $period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);



   foreach($period as $p)
   {
    $x =$p->format('Y-m-d');


    $sql ="INSERT INTO dt(data) VALUES('$x')";    

         $x = $connection->prepare($sql);

    if($x->execute())
```

Comment: Seu problema não ficou muito claro. Poderia dar detalhes?

Comment: Claro! Estou pegando um intervalo de datas e inserindo no banco como o código mostra. Faço isso por meio de um foreach que vai pegar esse intervalo do datePeriod. Gostaria de colocar condições dentro da captura desse intervalo de datas. Por exemplo, se nesse intervalo cair um dia da semana como sábado pula, não grava.Apenas um exemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, o `foreach` é só um laço de repetição, ou seja, iremos repetir um bloco de instruções **quaisquer**. Nesse caso, para cada elemento de $periodo haverá um laço de repetição.
Um exemplo de uma condição dentro do `foreach`, semelhante ao exemplo que você deu seria:

```
foreach($period as $p){
    $x =$p->format('Y-m-d');
    if(date('N', strtotime($p))== 6){ // // date('N', strtotime($p)) retorna um numero entre 0 (domingo) e 6 (sábado)
         $sql ="INSERT INTO dt(data) VALUES('$x')";    
         $x = $connection->prepare($sql);
         if($x->execute())
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Cara! Tentei executar como vc mostrou mas o erro "Notice: Undefined property: DatePeriod::$dayofweek" apareceu

Comment: Eu me equivoquei, achei que o $periodo era um objeto do Carbon. Vou editar a resposta seguindo esse código de exemplo: https://3v4l.org/dJ9q7

Comment: Perfeito cara! Me salvou vlw irmão deu certo.